# Npm install forces to install peer dependency yourself after Upgrade to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have recently upgraded my angular application from 6 to 7. When I do npm install the angular cli recommends installing peer dependencies yourself. When I try to install peer dependency by the following command, for example:

```
npm install @angular/common@^7.0.0
```

It adds the an entry in the dependencies section. So when I install one by one , an entry of the respective package is added under dependency. So finally I get the same entry of the package in two places. Does that make sense. Am i doing anything wrong. What I understand is that peer dependencies are only used while publishing the package so i could just ignore the warning am I right or do i need to install all the peer dependencies

Original package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@wtw/toolkit",
  "version": "44.0.5",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.4",
    "deep-diff": "1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
}
```

After running the npm install, I get this warning message:

```
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/http@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/router@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of core-js@^2.5.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wtw/toolkit@44.0.5 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.26 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-click-outside@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-click-outside@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

My new package.json would like like

```
{
  "name": "@wtw/platform",
  "version": "44.0.15",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@wtw/toolkit": "44.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.24.7",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "3.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-jsoneditor": "^0.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.3.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this package is consumed by another package. So every time I make change to this package , I publish it to be consumed by another package.